# Ubuntu flash drive does not detect existing OS on SSD

Tags: system-installation, ssd

I want to remove Windows 10 from my Lenovo Y720, which comes with Windows installed on an SSD, and has a separate regular hard drive.

[image]

But it seems that only the regular hard drive is detected. It told me there is currently no OS on the system, which there definitely is.

How can I remove Windows and install Ubuntu in this situation?

Comment: Many new systems need both UEFI update from vendor and SSD firmware update. You should do that even if not installing Ubuntu. Have you done that. Other issues can be that Windows fast start up is on which sets hibernation flag preventing Linux from correctly seeing NTFS partitions, or UEFI has drive(s) set for RAID or Intel SRT, not AHCI. But if you change to AHCI, be sure to install Windows AHCI drivers first.

Comment: It prompted me to update the BIOS and i did. Fast start up is disabled - otherwise it won't even read from the USB ports. I do recall seeing Intel SRT. Let me check that.

Comment: Hm, no it doesn't have Intel SRT, and i'd set to boot in Legacy mode instead of UEFI. It does have something called Intel Platform Trust Technology. Disabling that didn't help.

Comment: I am considering removing the SSD and having it wiped by connecting it to another computer.

Comment: Did you also update firmware for SSD?

Comment: @oldfred No, i forgot about that. I don't know how to go about that. Let me see what i can do about that.

Comment: According to Lenovo's utility for this, there are no firmware updates for this SSD

Comment: Fast start up in Windows is different than fast boot in UEFI. Both need to be off. Not sure what else to suggest. Once UEFI & firmware are most current versions, SSD are normally seen, if in AHCI mode.

Comment: @oldfred Ok, i turned off fast startup too - thanks - but still the installation program doesn't detect the SSD. And I thought, ok, i'll install on the hard drive, then make it the boot drive, and then see what i can do about the SSD. But, the BIOS doesn't list the hard drive as a boot option. Will it do so if i install Ubuntu on it? I guess it can't hurt to try.

Comment: If newer computer, it will be UEFI which highly recommends gpt partitioning. Windows only installs in UEFI boot mode from gpt partitioned drives. And Ubuntu & Windows need to be in same boot mode. Another Lenovo: Lenovo Legion Y520-15I  Installer does not detect SSD and HDD: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359208

Comment: @oldfred i did install on the hard drive, and Ubuntu is working. And yes, the SSD still isn't detected, so i can't even wipe it from Ubuntu on the other drive. However i'm still a lot happier than if i was forced to use Windows 10. I will look further into how to wipe that drive and make it accessible to the system. I might take it to a shop to see if they can wipe it.

Comment: @oldfred PS, thanks for your dedicated service.

Comment: I might look at SSD's vendor site for firmware updates. My Samsung SSD has software on the Samsung site for updating it. https://superuser.com/questions/1292332/how-to-update-samsungs-ssd-firmware But Linux version is in commercial, not consumer.